# How to display data fetched from the database table into listview?

Tags: java, android

My Function In `SQLAdapter class` is

```
public ArrayList<Airline> getairlinedetails(String bookingdate) {

    Cursor curCalllog =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ BOOK + 
            " WHERE " + date + 
            " BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "'", null);

    if (curCalllog != null) {
        if (curCalllog.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                a=new Airline();
                //a.setBookingdate(curCalllog.getString(1));
                a.setPickupadd(curCalllog.getString(2));
                a.setCity(curCalllog.getString(3));
                a.setTrip(curCalllog.getString(4));
                a.setFdate(curCalllog.getString(5));
                a.setFtime(curCalllog.getString(6));
                a.setCdate(curCalllog.getString(7));
                a.setPtime(curCalllog.getString(8));
                a.setSeats(curCalllog.getInt(9));
                a.setAmount(curCalllog.getInt(10));



                update.add(a);
            } while (curCalllog.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    return update;
}
```

M Fetching data between two dates and
I Want To show the fetched data into listview please help me how to do it I m new in android development.

Comment: You can pass your ArrayList into the Adapter class of your ListView and access the data from the arraylist in your adapter class's getView method.

Comment: Can You Please post some code here for reference please

Answer (score 1):

You can use  SimpleCursorAdapter for showing Databse contents in Listview. Make instance of  SimpleCursorAdapter and pass Cursor object into it. [Refer](http://joesapps.blogspot.in/2011/02/customized-listview-data-display-in.html) this link

If you want Customized Listview, you can customize SimpleCursorAdapter by extending this with your custom adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting data from database and there by complete ArrayList with Airline objects.

Now to display data in ListView from `ArrayList<Airline>`, you have to define **Custom adapter class** by extending either `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter`.

Here you go: [How to define custom adapter for ListView?](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+custom+adapter+for+listview)

Comment: is there any tutorial which will help me because m totaly new in Android

Comment: @sonam Ok fine. But as you are novice android programmer, I would suggest you to learn and explore [**ListView**](http://www.technotalkative.com/category/listview) category given on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

> I Want To show the fetched data into listview please help me how to do
> it I m new in android development

Simpliest way is to use `ArrayAdapter` with build-in `ListView's` row layout.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourList);
ArrayList<Airline> data = db.getairlinedetails("someString");
ArrayAdapter<Airline> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Airline>(this, 
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But since this you need to also override `toString()` method in your Airline class.

**Reason** is that your `ArrayAdapter` will convert each child(provided list of airlines) to String and if you won't override toString() you will get default string representation of object but you probably need to show for instance name of airline so your method can looks like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return this.name;
}
```

### Note:

This is simple way. But if you want to get more control over ListView and create custom list i recommend you to create own subclass of ListAdapter for example BaseAdapter and define your own Adapter. Sorry but i won't write you implementation because it requires much more code but nice examples you can find here:

- [Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)
- [Android ListView, ListActivity and ListFragment - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)
- [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: @sonam what kind of problem?

Comment: Actuly m successful in showing records in texviews....but it is for one record....i want to display more records with four fields in listview.......still m working on custom listview its damn confusing :( :(  any ways really Thanks for the help

Comment: @sonam so in my answer you have links on clear tutorials where is everthing explained. where you have a problem? what is confusing for you? tell me.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this example :

**DataManipulator.java** -helper class

```
 //to retrieve data in a list
  public List<String[]> selectAll()
{

    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id","name","number","skypeId","address" },
            null, null, null, null, "name asc"); 

    int x=0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String[] b1=new String[]{cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4)};

            list.add(b1);

            x=x+1;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    } 
    cursor.close();

    return list;
}
```

**CheckData.java**
          // to show data in a list view

```
      public class CheckData extends ListActivity  {     
TextView selection;
public int idToModify; 
DataManipulator dm;

List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<String[]> names2 =null ;
String[] stg1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.check);
      dm = new DataManipulator(this);
      names2 = dm.selectAll();

    stg1=new String[names2.size()]; 

    int x=0;
    String stg;

    for (String[] name : names2) {
        stg = name[1]+" - "+name[2]+ " - "+name[3]+" - "+name[4];

        stg1[x]=stg;
        x++;
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(   
            this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,   
            stg1);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);

}      

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(stg1[position]);
}


}
```

follow this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for complete tutorial